# Copyright and Fair use: Logos

Tags: copyright, fair-use

Some companies have written articles about my website. Many of the articles were also interviews.

My question is - can I use the Logos of the companies on my website under the "fair use" without written agreement? It would be in a section "companies who have written about us" (something about that for the section name).

Thank you

Comment: I was about to VTC, but after a closer look, I think we should leave this open. The question has certainly been asked before, but it hasn't really been answered, at least not in any helpful way. The linked question has two answers, neither accepted, and reaching opposite conclusions. I think we're better off leaving this open in hopes of attracting a high-quality answer.